# Google Play Services Games SignIn with AndEngine

Tags: andengine, google-play-services, google-play-games

i'm trying to achieve a simple login in my game

I have inherited my MainActivity from google BaseGameActivity.

When i start the game, nothing happens (in the doc says it would show a popup for login).

If i try to call the beginUserInitiatedSignIn() method from the Helper class, in the log a warning says that the connection is already running!

There also is a new info from PopupManager, that i have not selected a view for popups, but i have found nothing to configure this..

Thank you